# SQL ERD- primary key appears twice

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, erd

**How can we deal with a scenario that the same primary key appears more than once?**

***Scenario Example:***

*Let's suppose I have SQL-SERVER Database of Fire station.*

*We would like to create a table that **connects** between a **call request** to a **fire fighter***

***Table:***

> - *Call Requests*
> - *Firefighters*

***The table looks like:***

> ```
> [Call_Request_Code[INT, PRIMARY KEY], Firefighter[ID, FOREIGN KEY] ]
> ```

**For example:**

> Request_Code-222 , firefighters ID's- 987 and 777.*

**The problem is that it will have 222 twice
Since the same primary key appear twice an exception will be thrown.**

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Call_Request_Code is Primary Key.
If i understood your request you should remove the primary key from Call_Request_Code and applay primary key constraint on both the fields.